# SCSI virtual disks not showing up on RHEL 7.X KVM guests

Tags: redhat, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, scsi

For whatever reason I can't get my virtual disks to show up on any of my RHEL 7.X guests (libvirt + KVM). The XML is configured just like my other guests so I know it isn't an issue on that end. It almost seems like my VMs are missing a SCSI driver or something but it's difficult to tell.

/proc/scsi/scsi has no entries in it and none of the disks are in /dev or /dev/disk/by-*. I'm not exactly sure what I should be looking for, so if anyone has any ideas about why this would happen please let me know.

Comment: Try running `modprobe virtio_scsi` and see...

Comment: Tried this but it didn't give any output. Tried in verbose mode as well  but I got nothing from it. If that driver was missing I assume I'd get an error. How can I verify that this driver is loaded and working properly?

Comment: What does `lsblk` say? The disks could be either `virtio` (showing as `/dev/vdX`) or `virtio-scsi` ones (which would show as `/dev/sdX`). Could you post the xml? We the VM installed using anaconda or created from an image another way?

Answer (score 0):

I see. If these are `virtio` only, and not `virtio-scsi` devices, I can reproduce in a VM. I have opened a Bugzilla at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1348664.